# Password Safe app for Mac and iOS

Tags: osx, ios, password-manager

I'm using [Password Safe](http://passwordsafe.sourceforge.net/index.shtml) on my PCs, but recently I aquired some Apple devices including my work laptop. I looked at the [related projects](http://passwordsafe.sourceforge.net/relatedprojects.shtml) and tried one (Password Gorilla). It turns out to be a little unresponsive on my MacBook Pro. I also decided I would like to access my passwords from my iPod Touch. So I'm looking around for another option. The most likely choices seem to be [pwSafe](http://app77.com/pwSafe/) and [pwSafeMac](http://app77.com/pwSafeMac/). I don't mind spending $12.98 for the pair, but that seems a lot to invest given that there seem to be free options floating around.

**My must haves:**

- Support Password Safe V3 files stored on Dropbox.
- Generate new passwords according to password policy stored in the file.
- Passwords can be copied to the clipboard with minimal effort.
- Notification of expiring passwords. (Password Safe falls short here.)
- No subscription fees.

**My nice to haves:**

- Unified interface on all platforms. (Including the PC if possible.)
- Free or inexpensive.
- Is easy enough to use and install that I can recommend it to my grandmother. (None of the options I've tried come close.)

Comment: I personally use KeePassX(Mac) and MiniKeePass(iOS).
But it lacks in some of your needs. Well.. It is free and it is widely spread. If you don't mind trying it, I can recommend that.

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to migrate your Windows machines, and spring for the Mac/Windows bundle ($70), I think you may like [1Password](https://agilebits.com/onepassword).

You can import your Password Safe v3 files, as detailed [here](http://help.agilebits.com/1Password3/import_passwords.html).

You'll get an Android and/or iPhone management app, too.